# How to implement the NanoHttpd server and utilize in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, nanohttpd

I would like to implement the 'NanoHttpd' server call in my 'MainActivity'. In my MainActivity, I am receiving two text inputs values and calling another activity 'ValidCodeReceived'and passing these values. How can I call `NanoHttpd` in my MainActivity and get these values  ? Please advise

// 'NanoHttpd' server code:

```
public class MyServer extends NanoHTTPD {
    private final static int PORT = 8080;

    public MyServer() throws IOException {
        super(PORT);
        start();        
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {   

        return new NanoHTTPD.Respon( );
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        server = new MyServer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(server != null) {
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

//Existing 'MainActivity'  code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText inputName, inputCode;
    public static  String strName = null;
    public static  String strCode = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        inputName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#63d0f2"));
        inputCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCode);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.displayMap);  


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                strName = inputName.getText().toString();
                strCode = inputCode.getText().toString();
                String myCode = inputCode.getText().toString();

                if(inputName.getText().length()<3 || inputName.getText() ==null ){                    
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter valid name !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (inputCode.getText().length()<4){

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a valid code !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(myCode.matches("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Code cannot be blank !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else if(!myCode.matches(".*[A-Za-z].*") && !myCode.matches(".*[0-9].*") && !myCode.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]*")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Code field should have alpha numeric values",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ValidCodeReceived.class);                    
                    intent.putExtra("mainname", strName);
                    intent.putExtra("maincode", strCode);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

//ValidCodeReceived

```
public class ValidCodeReceived extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if( getIntent().getExtras() != null)
        {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String myData1 = intent.getStringExtra("mainname");
            String myData2 = intent.getStringExtra("maincode");
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(20);
            textView.setText("Hello team, send by:"+ myData1 + " "+ myData2);
            setContentView(textView);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a webserver within an activity? That looks like an odd thing to do. I suspect you'd need to use at least a background thread to start the server because it looks like blocking code. Also can you explain what you mean by "How can I call NanoHttpd in my MainActivity and get these values"?

Comment: you'd need an `HTTP` client. while it is quite pointless to fetch from `127.0.0.1` ... `NanoHTTPD` is rather suitable as a web-server for the local network (other hosts, but the localhost).

Comment: @MartinZeitler: I didn't know that,  I thought the NanoHTTP will do the whole stuff..

Comment: @zapl: I was thinking that I would be able to create a `web server` using Nanohttpd,  and I was looking for some advise on how to create a web server and how to implement that in my activity.

Comment: You can do that if you want to, I just don't understand who or what should be using the webserver, i.e. send http requests to it, what content it should serve, how all that relates to your activities and such. I can't give you an answer what you should do without understanding what you try to do :)

Comment: ok, I will add more. I was looking for `servlets` kind of similar component in android that can extends the capabilities of a server.